Deploying Next.js with pm2 - how to minimize project footprint?
I start to set up a pm2 deployment for a simple Next.js webpage.
If I do pm2 deploy production setup, the whole git repo is cloned to the server's webspace (into /public_html/source).
As Next.js is a Node application, the build process requires additional disk space during build (for node_modules/). And those modules remain after build at the server.
I don't want this, as I want to keep the production webspace as lean as possible.
Is there a way to use pm2 in the way that the build appears on a local PC (or within a GitLab CI runner VM) and just the result of the build will be deployed to the server?
If not, do you have any other suggestion how to achieve this?

Exactly what you describe, yes - do the build in e.g. GitLab CI, then deploy only the build outputs (assuming you're using static exports - Next.js does need runtime Node in some circumstances).

I got it to work now. The way to make it work in my case are as following: In my ecosystem.config.js I'd added a post-deploy value, where I do execute yarn && yarn build. After this I do execute a script, that cleanup all the trash from the Server.
It's ok for my current use-case, as I have many diskspace at this webserver that can be used during build-time. I just clean it up to not mess up the server with unnecessary trash.
But you are also right, if disk-space is the issue, it is better to do anything in gitlab-runner and just copy the final build to the target server.
